# Do closed questions earn the Famous Question badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

Specifically, [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97475/whats-the-most-money-actors-earned-for-star-trek-in-each-era)...

Comment: Was this a ploy to get closer to it. Anyways if you're on the site simply to earn internet points, I suggest you reconsider your priorities :)

Comment: @Edlothiad.   Well, it was a legitimate question I had, but I wasn't exactly avoiding the side effect.

Comment: It's my point to everyone. Too many people just see the rep (like that asker today, I saw this question with 100 upvotes I want some too). SE is building a repository of information, not a place to get internet points.

Comment: @Edlothiad, well, that all fine and dandy, but if you think that's really the case and everyone will selflessly subscribe to the same philosophy, then why are there points and badges at all?

Comment: I ask myself the same thing.. :(

Comment: @Edlothiad i concur. nothing is worse that users who are only interested in having more review points than everyone else.

Comment: @KutuluMike I don't know, rep-hoarders are definitely worse than review hoarders...

Answer (score 7):

## Yes.

You'll find several cases of this around the network. See, e.g., on Meta.SE, [Why do questions closed as too specific count for question badges (e.g. Famous)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285862/294691). For a random example, see on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=12359) - the user earned the Famous Question badge, and the question has been closed for over two years.

[image]

[image]